# VUE 2 Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to route HomeView.vue view to App.vue and this is my code.
...............................................................

> Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router/index'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
vuetify,
router,
render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

> App.vue

```
<template>
<router-view />
</template>

<script setup></script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

> HomeView.vue

```
<template>
<p>Home</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
<style lang=""></style>
```

> Router/indes.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const routes = [
   {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
 },
]

const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory(),
routes,
})

export default router
```

I tride use ".$use(router)" before .$mount(#app)
Someone can help?

Comment: Please share your code as text

Comment: which version of vue/vue router do you want to use?

Comment: Vue 2.7.14 and i have vue-router 4.1.6

Comment: I also use vuetify if that matters

Comment: The info on package versions should have been in the question. vue-router 4 is for vue 3. Case closed